# Login page accept any password

Tags: javascript, php, html, server

I have a xamp based webserver and I installed attendance system , I have 10 users registered to enter their attendance by login individually... issue is in login page accept any password and not giving error that password is wrong. Like you enter user id john@abcd.com & password gfjhgh its accept and entered to index page , the original password is 123456 but its accept every thing you type. Please tell me how to solve. It should says that you entered wrong password and can not login.

Code is below:- Complete sign-in.php

```
<?php
// Check if install.php is present
if(is_dir('install')) {
    header("Location: install/install.php");
} else {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Access DB Info
    include('config.php');

    // Get Settings Data
    include ('includes/settings.php');
    $set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($setRes);

    // Include Functions
    include('includes/functions.php');

    // Include Sessions & Localizations
    include('includes/sessions.php');

    // Check if the User is all ready signed in
    if ((isset($_SESSION['tz']['userId'])) && ($_SESSION['tz']['userId'] != '')) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    $msgBox = '';
    $installUrl = $set['installUrl'];
    $siteName   = $set['siteName'];
    $siteEmail  = $set['siteEmail'];

    // Account Log In
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'signIn') {
        if($_POST['emailAddy'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($accEmailReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else if($_POST['password'] == '') {
            $msgBox = alertBox($accPassReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else {
            $usrEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailAddy']);

            $check = "SELECT userId, userFirst, userLast, isActive FROM users WHERE userEmail = '".$usrEmail."'";
            $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check) or die('-1' . mysqli_error());
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

            if ($count > 0) {
                // If the account is Active - Allow the login
                if ($row['isActive'] == '1') {
                    $userEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailAddy']);
                    $password = encodeIt($_POST['password']);

                    if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
                                            SELECT
                                                userId,
                                                userEmail,
                                                userFirst,
                                                userLast,
                                                location,
                                                superUser,
                                                isAdmin
                                            FROM
                                                users
                                            WHERE
                                                userEmail = ?
                                                AND password = ?
                    ")) {
                        $stmt -> bind_param("ss",
                                            $userEmail,
                                            $password
                        );
                        $stmt -> execute();
                        $stmt -> bind_result(
                                    $userId,
                                    $userEmail,
                                    $userFirst,
                                    $userLast,
                                    $location,
                                    $superUser,
                                    $isAdmin
                        );
                        $stmt -> fetch();
                        $stmt -> close();

                        if (!empty($userId)) {
                            if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();
                            $_SESSION['tz']['userId']       = $userId;
                            $_SESSION['tz']['userEmail']    = $userEmail;
                            $_SESSION['tz']['userFirst']    = $userFirst;
                            $_SESSION['tz']['userLast']     = $userLast;
                            $_SESSION['tz']['location']     = $location;
                            $_SESSION['tz']['superUser']    = $superUser;
                            $_SESSION['tz']['isAdmin']      = $isAdmin;

                            // Add Recent Activity
                            $activityType = '1';
                            $tz_uid = $userId;
                            $activityTitle = $userFirst.' '.$userLast.' '.$accSignInAct;
                            updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                            // Update the Last Login Date for User
                            $sqlStmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET lastVisited = NOW() WHERE userId = ?");
                            $sqlStmt->bind_param('s', $userId);
                            $sqlStmt->execute();
                            $sqlStmt->close();

                            header('Location: index.php');
                        } else {
                            // Add Recent Activity
                            $activityType = '0';
                            $tz_uid = '0';
                            $activityTitle = $accSignInErrAct;
                            updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                            $msgBox = alertBox($accSignInErrMsg, "<i class='fa fa-warning'></i>", "warning");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Add Recent Activity
                    $activityType = '0';
                    $tz_uid = $row['userId'];
                    $activityTitle = $row['userFirst'].' '.$row['userLast'].' '.$signInUsrErrAct;
                    updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                    // If the account is not active, show a message
                    $msgBox = alertBox($inactAccMsg, "<i class='fa fa-warning'></i>", "warning");
                }
            } else {
                // Add Recent Activity
                $activityType = '0';
                $tz_uid = '0';
                $activityTitle = $noAccSignInErrAct;
                updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                // No account found
                $msgBox = alertBox($noAccSignInErrMsg, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
            }
        }
    }

    // Reset Account Password
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'resetPass') {
        // Validation
        if ($_POST['accountEmail'] == "") {
            $msgBox = alertBox($accEmailReq, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
        } else {
            $usrEmail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['accountEmail']);

            $query = "SELECT userEmail FROM users WHERE userEmail = ?";
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("s",$usrEmail);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($emailUser);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();

            if ($numrows == 1) {
                // Generate a RANDOM Hash for a password
                $randomPassword = uniqid(rand());

                // Take the first 8 digits and use them as the password we intend to email the Employee
                $emailPassword = substr($randomPassword, 0, 8);

                // Encrypt $emailPassword for the database
                $newpassword = encodeIt($emailPassword);

                //update password in db
                $updatesql = "UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE userEmail = ?";
                $update = $mysqli->prepare($updatesql);
                $update->bind_param("ss",
                                        $newpassword,
                                        $usrEmail
                                    );
                $update->execute();

                $qry = "SELECT userId, userFirst, userLast, isAdmin FROM users WHERE userEmail = '".$usrEmail."'";
                $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry) or die('-2' . mysqli_error());
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
                $theUser = $row['userId'];
                $isAdmin = $row['isAdmin'];
                $userName = $row['userFirst'].' '.$row['userLast'];

                if ($isAdmin == '1') {
                    // Add Recent Activity
                    $activityType = '3';
                    $activityTitle = $userName.' '.$admPassResetAct;
                    updateActivity($theUser,$activityType,$activityTitle);
                } else {
                    // Add Recent Activity
                    $activityType = '3';
                    $activityTitle = $userName.' '.$usrPassResetAct;
                    updateActivity($theUser,$activityType,$activityTitle);
                }

                $subject = $siteName.' '.$resetPassEmailSub;

                $message = '<html><body>';
                $message .= '<h3>'.$subject.'</h3>';
                $message .= '<p>'.$resetPassEmail1.'</p>';
                $message .= '<hr>';
                $message .= '<p>'.$emailPassword.'</p>';
                $message .= '<hr>';
                $message .= '<p>'.$resetPassEmail2.'</p>';
                $message .= '<p>'.$resetPassEmail3.' '.$installUrl.'sign-in.php</p>';
                $message .= '<p>'.$emailTankYouTxt.'<br>'.$siteName.'</p>';
                $message .= '</body></html>';

                $headers = "From: ".$siteName." <".$siteEmail.">\r\n";
                $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$siteEmail."\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

                mail($usrEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

                $msgBox = alertBox($resetPassMsg1, "<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>", "success");
                $stmt->close();
            } else {
                // Add Recent Activity
                $activityType = '1';
                $tz_uid = '0';
                $activityTitle = $resetPassMsgAct;
                updateActivity($tz_uid,$activityType,$activityTitle);

                // No account found
                $msgBox = alertBox($resetPassMsg2, "<i class='fa fa-times-circle'></i>", "danger");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why a second select on `users`? `$row` should already have all info, just select the password field too. The second thing I see is that the password check is based on the `if (!empty($userId))` which in turn is based on [`bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-result-returnvalues). Docs say that `bind_result` will return false if it fails to bind (ie no rows returned). Shouldn't this be the `if` that decides login or failure?

Comment: In general I would change the logic to only select once all the required fields. Then (1) check num rows, (2) check active (3) encode and compare passes... any of the above fails, set a message and return

Comment: If you're going to user `header()` to perform a redirect, you should be using an `exit;` immediately after. Otherwise, you're executing the rest of the page for not reason.

Answer (score 0):

Place

`$stmt->store_result();`

after `$stmt -> execute();` and before `$stmt->bind_result(....);`

Make sure to place `$stmt -> close()` at the end of the your all conditions.

and Check whats the result of your `$userId` is returning Before if `(!empty($userId)) { .... }`

Comment: i added $stmt->store_result(); after $stmt -> execute(); and before $stmt->bind_result(....); and sure to place $stmt -> close() at the end of the your all conditions. but still all users can logins with every password like klklfjnbjfhg but original password is 123456 (can you guys please edit the whole code correctly and give me ??) i am not a developer :(

Answer (score 0):

i added $stmt->store_result(); after $stmt -> execute(); and before $stmt->bind_result(....); and sure to place $stmt -> close() at the end of the your all conditions. but still all users can logins with every password like klklfjnbjfhg but original password is 123456